# How to Vuestic DataTable displays values from properties of objects?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuestic, vuestic-admin

I'm using Vuestic in my vue project and I need to display values from a property that is in a object, I have something like this:

```
myObject: {
  subObject: {
    name
  }
}
```

I have a list of myObject and I need to display the name of the subObject in the DataTable. My DataTable is pointing to headers object:

```
headers: [
  { key: 'subObject.name', label: 'Name' }
]
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is defintely possible.

This feature was not supported until [this commit](https://github.com/epicmaxco/vuestic-ui/commit/0c4c1c3bf6f77e781fd1fb611018a91beb5d863c) on Jun 23.
Therefore, since v1.4.2 of `vuestic-ui` was released on Jun 24, you can use dot notation in keys to retrieve nested properties for data tables.

Here is a working example: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-5duwah?file=src%2FApp.vue&terminal=dev).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will update to this version.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but it sounds like you would like to create an array of `myObject.subObject.name` values from another array of `myObject` objects?

You can do that with [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
myObjectArray.map((obj) => {
  return {
    key: obj.subObject.name,
  };
});
```

the above code would take an array like this:

```js
myObjectArray = [
  { subObject: { name: "a" } },
  { subObject: { name: "b" } },
  { subObject: { name: "c" } },
]
```

and return this:

```js
[
  { key: "a" },
  { key: "b" },
  { key: "c" },
]
```

you could assign the result to a computed property.  I'm not sure where your `label` values comes from but I'm sure you could modify the above code to include it

Comment: In fact not. I'll try to clarify. I have a Exam class in TS with some properties (like id, name) and in this class I have objects too (like Client with properties like id, name). I have an array of Exam and need to show the properties inside the Client object in my list. I don't now if the Vuestic DataTable component allows that, maybe I need to use the method you referenced to create a new object with all properties I need.